# Segmented message distribution for marketing

Tags: php, laravel, email

I need to make message (email/telegram/sms and etc) distribution for my project.
It needs to be separated to each user list (new accounts, paid accounts, were paid and etc) and sending provider (email, telegram ..)

Is there any open source or paid solutions? (perefer laravel or just php, but it doesnt really matter)

How do you solve it in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions:

- Is there any open source or paid solutions?

I would clearly use Laravel Notifications as you said you prefered, Laravel, php and open source all in one. There are many drivers, the ones you have mentioned included, you can check them [here](http://laravel-notification-channels.com/).

- How do you solve it in your project?

About how you would integrate that in user groups you need to use the trait Notifiable:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Then you just need to create the collection of users you are interested in notifying and send them the notification using the Facade:

```
Notification::send($users, new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

Just as an extra advice I would recommend you to set up your queues and queue those notifications since your users groups could be big:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class InvoicePaid extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This is not segmented message auto-distribution depends on "user list"

Comment: @KirillBurkhanov You can fill the variable `$users` with any list you want. To automate it use events.

Comment: Anyway - This is not segmented message auto-distribution depends on "user list"

i didnt ask you how to implement this with laravel. I know how to do that.

Question is about different thing

Comment: @KirillBurkhanov Well I think I answered both of your questions perfectly, you may not like the answer but is completly valid.